# Python Anaconda: Install Module/Library on an Intranet Computer

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to Python and am clueless about installing module/library on Anaconda. I need step-by-step instructions on how to install on an Intranet computer.

1. Where do I download the module/library (eg regex module) on an Internet computer?
2. Where do I save the module in my intranet computer which is where I want to install the module?
3. What are the commands to install the module?
4. Do I run the commands in Anaconda prompt?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I need some clarification before I can answer this. When you say "intranet computer," do you mean a computer which is not connected to the Internet at all, but has access to a LAN? If so, do any computers on the LAN have access to the Internet?

Conda/Anaconda are package managers, which means they are meant to remove the complication of saving and loading packages manually. You use the command line (or, if you want, a GUI interface) to add these packages, either globally or to your Python environment (it's generally considered best practices to install to Python environments for specific projects). So you don't normally need to worry about where to save the files - the downloading and saving is taken care of by Anaconda. In fact, this is the point!

If you're working off of a computer with only intranet access, there may be a way to mirror the repository sources, but this is going to be complicated and you're going to need access to a computer that can access the Internet. Can you answer this clarifying question for me: can you access google.com or this page itself or any other webpage on the public Internet from the computer you want to use Anaconda on?

EDIT Sept 22, 2020: if your computer is offline but you have access to an online computer that can transfer files, [this official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/mirrors/) covers how to set up local repositories.

Comment: Hi Ellie, My intranet computer with Anaconda is UNABLE to access google.com or any other webpage. I can download the module on an INTERNET computer and save/transfer to the intranet computer, if that is going to help. Thanks

Comment: Hi there! So [Anaconda's official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/config/mirrors/) covers how to set up a local mirror of a repository. I've never actually done this, but it seems like it's designed for precisely your situation - download the files on your internet-exposed computer, and then move them to your intranet system and set them up as described.